# Design issue on stack overflow talent - title in mobile web view

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, stack-overflow-talent

When seeing the [Stack Overflow Talent](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent) in the mobile web view, there is a display issue with that. In the title **stack overflow TALENT**, the color of the text "stack overflow" is same as the background color, so it not visible.

Steps to reproduce in mobile web view:

- Click the "Stack Overflow Talent" link in the footer or directly go to the [Stack Overflow Talent](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent) page.
- Click the menu option [image: Menu] in the right hand side top.
- Now scroll the page, you can see the design issue in the title as in the screenshot below.

[image: Stack Overflow text color is not transparent]